# Can I get Socratic badge after asking 3 more questions on GDSE?

Tags: discussion

According to definition of `Socratic` badge:

> Ask a well-received question on 100 separate days, and maintain a
> positive question record

I've discussed it before and I came to know that I might get it after asking 3 more questions (97 currently). But I don't want people laugh at me if I don't get it. So I want to understand the definition. It seems a bit tricky/mathematical.

I'm also doubtful because in my profile, next badge is mentioned as `Fanatic`, not `Socratic`. After all, I feel it would be too easy to get this award, which has not been awarded before, by just asking 100 questions. So there might be some terms and conditions.

Comment: All your questions need to be positive in score. So no negatives.

Comment: @joojaa so that way I'll need to count positive 100 questions? Or *new* continuous 100 positive questions?

Comment: And 0 votes will be counted or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### No

---

*Well-received question* = At least one upvote on a question. So question with 0 votes won't be considered well received

*Positive question record* doesn't just mean 100 questions without any downvotes. It also involves other questions like the closed ones, downvoted etc. And calculated by considering all questions.

Details are discussed under [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262814/7034388) and [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24803/298955) question.